# Create an application pool that uses .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, iis-7, directoryservices, application-pool

I use the following code to create a app pool:

```
var metabasePath = string.Format(@"IIS://{0}/W3SVC/AppPools", serverName);
DirectoryEntry newpool;
DirectoryEntry apppools = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
newpool = apppools.Children.Add(appPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool");
newpool.CommitChanges();
```

How do I specify that the app pool should use .NET Framework 4.0?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I see from the tags you're using IIS7. Unless you absolutely have to, don't use the IIS6 compatibility components. Your preferred approach should be to use the [`Microsoft.Web.Administration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx) managed API.

To create an application pool using this and set the .NET Framework version to 4.0, do this:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
...

using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  ApplicationPool newPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add("MyNewPool");
  newPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
  serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

You should add a reference to `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` which can be found in:

> `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\InetSrv`

Comment: Yes. I've switched to ServerManager. The problem was that I didn't know where the DLL for System.Web.Administration was located. The answer is `%WinDir%\System32\InetSrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`

Comment: `Microsoft.Web.Administration` can also be added as a NuGet Package now rather than referencing the dll directly

Comment: No problem. It's from an deleted answer below. (And everything is CC licensed)

Comment: Hi Kev - I don't think you've added the Nuget part yet.  One upvote from me for this answer though :)

Answer (score 8):

```
newpool.Properties["ManagedRuntimeVersion"].Value = "v4.0";
```

Will do the same thing as the Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll but using DirectoryEntry

Also

```
newPool.InvokeSet("ManagedPipelineMode", new object[] { 0 });
```

Will switch to integrated or classic pipeline mode using DirectoryEntry.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are better in your particular scenario, but in general keep in mind that you can use the appcmd tool to do this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784%28v=ws.10%29.aspx.  Specifically:

`appcmd add apppool /name: string /managedRuntimeVersion: string /managedPipelineMode: Integrated | Classic`